# Will URLs with spaces in the path work on all major browsers?

Tags: 7, uri

Will a path to content such as `example.com/content type/page name` work? or must it have a filler such as dashes -  `example.com/content-type/page-name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spaces should be at least encoded as **%20** .

It's not a good practice, not a standard, to use spaces in URLs at all. In my opinion it is better to replace all spaces with dashes or to concatenate them.

Spaces will cause problems with links, for example you might get:

- [www.example.com/problem](http://www.example.com/problem) with link

instead of:

- [www.example.com/problem with link](http://www.example.com/problem%20with%20link)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547783/do-spaces-in-your-url-20-have-a-negative-impact-on-seo